# How to retrieve Jira issues via REST API when query contains a space

Tags: jira-rest-api

I'm trying to retrieve all issues from a project that are status "New Ticket". The status name having a space in it is completely tripping me up.

My command looks like the following. This works perfectly if status is a single word, like `Closed`, but fails on the spacing in `New Ticket`.

```
curl -D- \
  -u user:password \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"jql":"project = DEVOPS AND status = New Ticket", "fields":["id","key","summary","description"]}' \
  "https://projecturl.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search"
```

I've tried the following with no success;

```
"project = DEVOPS AND status = New Ticket"
"project = DEVOPS AND status = 'New Ticket'"
"project = DEVOPS AND status = %22New Ticket%22"
"project = DEVOPS AND status = \\u0025New Ticket\\u0025"
```

What's the right syntax?

Comment: have you tried %20 ?

Comment: @DaveB Anything using %'s returns `{"errorMessages":["Error in the JQL Query: The character '%' is a reserved JQL character. You must enclose it in a string or use the escape '\\u0025' instead. (line 1, character 31)"],"errors":{}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of messing around, it turns out you can just escape quotes inside the query, like so;

```
"project = DEVOPS AND status = \"New Ticket\""
```

Answer (score 0):

What about if it's a GET request and the request is in the URI, not in the POST data?

I have something similar to the following

```
/usr/bin/curl \
-s -u user@company.com:APIKEY -X GET \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://company.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?expand=changelog&jql=project=KEY%20and%20issueType=BUG
```

For me it's lopping off the %20and%20issueType=BUG part (and presumably dropping an error to STDERR and running it as if the jql is just project=KEY

EDIT:
This is starting to feel like a bug, even though it works just fine when you paste the URI into the browser.

Replacing the %20 with + made no difference. I get the same results either way.

The issue seems to be the presence of the expand=changelog and a JQL with spaces in it together. When I remove it, it works fine. When I put it at the end so that I have https://company.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=KEY+and+issueType=BUG&expand=changelog instead the JQL part works, and I get the a query of all the BUGs in KEY, but it ignores the expand=changelog part and I don't get the bug history of the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Ansible to open a ticket via jira!
To solve the error related to space between the words I just replace the space to "+" to replace the spaces, follow i.g:

Maybe this can help you ;)

```
    - name: Checking if the Jira issue already exist
      uri: 
        url: "{{ jira_server }}rest/api/3/search?jql=text~'{{ jira_subject | replace(' ','+')}}{{ jira_fw_type_operation }}'&project={{ jira_project }}"
        user: "{{ jira_user }}"
        password: "{{ jira_token }}"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        return_content: yes
        status_code: 200
        timeout: 60
        headers:
            Accept: "application/json"
      register: fetch_issue
      changed_when: fetch_issue['json']['total'] == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding single quote fix this:

```py
issues = jira.search_issues("project='Jira Service Desk'")
```